# ModuleNotFoundError when running BASH script on CMD

Tags: python, bash, cmd

I have a BASH script called `run2scripts.sh` that runs two python scripts at the same time. Here is the BASH script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python text_reader.py & python text_writer.py &
```

When I run the bash script on the CMD terminal, the result is:

```
>bash run2scripts.sh
File "text_reader.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

However, when I run the BASH script via Cygwin with `$ ./run2scripts.sh`, it works perfectly fine. Matplotlib works. I included in my `.bashrc` file `export PATH="PATH TO PYTHON INTERPRETER"` so python always goes to the path with all the modules installed. Furthermore, the command `where python` in CMD returns 2 results. `C:\Cygwin64\bin\python` and the path of the python interpreter with the modules installed. And CMD uses the latter path. The path to the interpreter is also apart of my PATH environment variable. So for these reasons, CMD shouldn't be returning a `ModuleNotFoundError`. `print(sys.path)` includes the path where Matplotlib is installed. The `which python` command in CMD however returns `/usr/bin/python`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I suspect the problem is related to the `which python` command and `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: In your Cygwin shell, what do you get if you run `which python`? Its possible your Cygwin PATH has a different ordering than your CMD PATH, which might cause your Cygwin shell to use a different python binary than your CMD. Also try running `python --version` in both CMD and Cygwin and see if the versions are the same.

Comment: Please try `command -v python` in Cygwin. If that also does not work, try `type -P python` in Cygwin.

Comment: `python --version` in Cygwin shell and CMD both give the same result. Python 3.9.0.

Comment: `command -v python` gives me the path to my Python 3.9 Interpreter (the one that I mostly use). `where python` in CMD gives me 2 results. `C:\Cygwin64\bin\python` (which is Python 3.6) and the path to my usual python interpreter (Python 3.9). `which python` gives the result `usr/bin/python`

Comment: @StarMan : From the error messages, you can already see that Python is indeed invoked perfectly well. Hence the whole problem is mainly a Python question, i.e. to get Python into finding the modules. Did you check [`sys.path`](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-does-python-find-imported-modules.cfm)?

Comment: @user1934428 I have edited the question.

Comment: @StarMan : What is a _CMD terminal_? Plus, I don't understand how your problem could possibly related to `PATH`.

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't just call that python code directly in cmd without changing shells to batch?  If there is a problem with the path, i don't think it's a `CMD` issue per-se, more like a `cygwin` issue about what path environment it is using when "loading cygwin 1st" vs. "instantiating the `bash` shell from the cmd prompt".  Try this, from within cygwin type `echo $PATH` then try at the cmd prompt `bash echo $PATH`.  I will bet you dollars to donust they are different and you need to tell the `bash` command where to get the path cygwin uses